# Boolean expression simplification homework - can you point out my error?

Tags: boolean-logic

As part of a homework assignment I must simplify the following (where '=NOT, .=AND, +=OR)

```
((A.B)+(A.C)+(B.C)).(ABC)'
```

I'm obviously not looking for someone to give me any sort of solution. However, I think it would be immensely helpful if someone could demonstrate where and how I'm misapplying a Boolean law (my terms keep zeroing out which is not a possible answer). I'll start by rewriting the rightmost factor.

```
((A.B)+(A.C)+(B.C)).(A'.B'.C')
```

Distribute

```
(A'.B'.C')(A.B)+(A'.B'.C')(A.C)+(A'.B'.C')(B.C)
```

Distribute and simplify leftmost term (A'A = 0)

```
(A'(A.B)).(B'(A.B)).(C'(A.B))+(A'.B'.C')(A.C)+(A'.B'.C')(B.C)

((A'A).(A'B)).((B'A).(B'B)).((C'A).(C'B))+(rightside expression)

((0).(A'B)).((B'A).(0)).((C'A).(C'B))+(rightside)

(0).(0).((C'A).(C'B))+(rightside)

((0).((C'A).(C'B))+(rightside)

(0)+(rightside)
```

I've concluded so far that, since the other 'rightside' terms have a similar structure they will also zero out leaving me with `0+0+0 = 0`. This cannot be correct since this equation is supposed to equate to another non-zero expression according to my assignment.

If you're curious my main resource for boolean laws is [electronic tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html)

Can you point out my error(s)?

Comment: Is `ABC` the same as `A.B.C`?

Comment: If only I'd have asked that... AND was described to me as the logical product, so so far I have assumed that yes that is true.

Comment: Then the first step is immediately wrong. `(A.B.C)' = A'+B'+C'`

Comment: Shoot! This is a case where I need DeMorgan's theorem isn't it... I'll redo the problem but this sounds like an answer if you want to demo/write an answer out.